# Общий скрин для разных пользователей

Tags: ubuntu, экран

Поискав в интернете, я пытался найти как сделать для разных пользователей общий скрин

к примеру у меня есть root и developer пользователи, я открыл скрин в root, есть ли у меня возможность открыть этот скрин в developer?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163872